# How to understand regular expression with python?

Tags: python, regex, string, escaping

I'm new with python. Could anybody help me on how I can create a regular expression given a list of strings like this:

```
  test_string =  "pero pero CC 
    tan tan RG
    antigua antiguo AQ0FS0
    que que CS 
    según según SPS00 
    mi mi DP1CSS 
    madre madre NCFS000"
```

How to return a tuple like this:

```
> ([madre, NCFS00],[antigua, AQ0FS0])
```

I would like to return the word with it's associated tag given test_string, this is what I've done:

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --
import re


#str = "pero pero CC " \
   "tan tan RG " \
   "antigua antiguo AQ0FS0" \
    "que que CS " \
    "según según SPS00 " \
    "mi mi DP1CSS " \
    "madre madre NCFS000"

tupla1 = re.findall(r'(\w+)\s\w+\s(AQ0FS0)', str)
print tupla1

tupla2 = re.findall(r'(\w+)\s\w+\s(NCFS00)',str)
print tupla2
```

The output is the following:

> [('antigua', 'AQ0FS0')] [('madre', 'NCFS00')]

The problem with this output is that if I pass it along `test_string` I need to preserve the "order" or "occurrence" of the tags (i.e. I only can print a tuple if and only if they have the following order: AQ0FS0 and NCFS000 in other words: female adjective, female noun).

Comment: And why not `[según, SPS00]`? In other words, what makes `[madre, NCFS00]` and `[antigua, AQ0FS0]` match?

Comment: try a website like regex101.com.

Comment: for the moment i only want to return the tags AQ0FS0 and NCFS00 with the word. I would like wo know how to create a regular expression given those tags, probably i will need to create more regex but this is just an example on how to aproach this task.

Comment: Why is `antiguo` not captured?  Does it have to be the first word in the line?

Comment: You really need the results in reverse order like that? Because I'm pretty sure that will make things more complicated.

Comment: To get you started: try `r'(\w+)\s\w+\s(AQ0FS0)'` and see what it matches. Figure out how to do the same thing with `NCFS00` instead of `AQ0FS0`. Then look at the `|` alternation operator. If you get stuck after trying that, show what you were able to get working and where you got stuck, and then you'll have a good question. (Put the code, etc. in the question, but also provide a link to your test at some site like Debuggex or Regex101, if you have one.)

Comment: You're getting downvoted because of the inconsistencies in your explanation vs. you're examples. If you do a little factoring, its as simple as `\b(w+)\s*(AQ0FS0|NCFS00)\b`

Comment: @sln: No it isn't. `antigua` is separated from `AQ0FS0` by a whole other word that he doesn't want, `antiguo`. [Try your pattern](https://www.debuggex.com/r/6IUU1IEtIT_WU3Xp). (Also, even after you fix the problems, why add the `\b`?)

Comment: @abarnert - How did you get that from his examples and description? One letter difference?

Comment: @sln: Well, he didn't answer Mike Christensen's question, but clearly your regex isn't going to provide the desired output, and one that picks the first word is. But again, your regex doesn't even provide the second word because of at least one typo, and I don't know why you've added the `\b` on each end if you're trying to simplify things.

Comment: @Sam thay match since both are female words

Answer (score 1):

```
^([a-zA-Z]+)\s+[a-zA-Z]+\s+([\w]+(?=\d$)\d)
```

Dont really know the basis for this selection but still you can get it like this.Just grab the captures.Dont forget to set the flags `g` and `m`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/38

Comment: why complicate it so much? `(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(\S+)` is so much easier.

Comment: @isedev that will give all lines.OP wants only `2`.just see the return tuple

Comment: What flags `g` and `m`? You realize that Python and PHP are not the same?